# Python Pyspark script fails on whole dataset but works on single file

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

[image]I have written a python pyspark script that extracts specific features from data . the script works fine on a single file.json and gives back a dataframe holding all my features as output . my problem is that I need the run the script on a whole dataset at once  (a folder containing my json files) . Can anyone suggest a good way to do it ? thanks[image: <code>my output features_dataframe</code>]

code sample :

```
spark= SparkSession.builder.appName('mySparkKPIs').master('local').getOrCreate()
finalDF = spark.read.json('final.json')
finalDF.createOrReplaceTempView("final")
######
treatment of different dataframes##"
F=df1.join(df2, on="num", how="inner")\
    .join(df3, on="num", how="inner")\
        .join(df4, on="num", how="inner")\
            .show()
```

Comment: You fail to show how exactly it is failing on the whole dataset. Or is it just that the question title is misleading?

Comment: I have just added screen shots of the error ...

Comment: @HristoIliev : I have tried two things in order to get my script to work from one file.json to a whole dataset : A) try to loop through all dataset ==>doesnt work , throws error as above . B) try to add the folder path to the dataset in the spark.read.json("") . ==> doesnt work neither . throws same error as above , and its a bit tricky since it's written in scala while my script is a python one .

Comment: you sure all your json files have the same schema?

Answer (score 1):

You can use as below:

```
finalDF = spark.read.json('/path/to/json/directory/*.json')
```

Comment: @ it says : an error occured while calling o***.json

Comment: the error says invalid character in the json file. Can you check the input json file? Also, you can read the json by providing schema separately.

Comment: I dont get it , it works on each of them when I specify the path separately , but doesnt loop over all of them .... when doing so , I get the error above .

Comment: @HoussemBZYWISH, are you sure it works if you specifically process `o542.json`? Because the error indeed indicates that the file contains non-UTF-32 data. If your file encoding is different, you need to specify it with the `"encoding"` reader option.